# Is store-type property in Spring Session no longer available?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

In the [Spring Session Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-jdbc.html#httpsession-jdbc-boot-spring-configuration) for Spring Boot Configuration, the first property explained is `spring.session.store-type=jdbc`. But in the [Spring Session section of the Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.1/reference/htmlsingle/#web.spring-session) this property is not listed. Also, this property is not listed among all the other [Web Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web).

Trying to disable the usage of a session store like explained in older documentations doesn't have any effect:

```
spring.session.store-type=none
```

The session storage gets created anyway.

Is it no longer possible to disable the session storage when `spring-session-jdbc` is added as dependency and thus Spring Boot will autoconfigure it for its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the migration guide it is not longer supported https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-session-store-type

You can define your own `SessionRepository` to override autoConfiguration.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that's what I was looking for, but for whatever reason couldn't find (I'm pretty sure I've read the migration guide some time ago...).